# Str.contains() where part of the string is variable

Tags: python

I'm working with an old game that contains rounds within matches. I need to find the output string that specifies "Round x of x" so I can perform a map adjustment dependent on the round.

In this case, there are 12 rounds, so the line will always be "Round x of 12". Additionally, each input is tested by the script to establish whether or not it meets given criteria. However, there are multiple lines that start with the word "round", so I decided to play it safe and test the whole line.

Therefore, I need to add a variable result within a definitive one:

`if line.contains("Round [variable] of 12")`

Is this possible in Python? Perhaps with regex? I considered using something like `[0-9]{2}`, but since the variable can be either one or two digits this would be unreliable.

Comment: Would it be "Round 1 of 12" or "Round 01 of 12"?

Comment: It's definitely the former. It's the same text that is displayed to the user, so it is "presented nicely".

Comment: Do you have an example of the `variable`?

Comment: @user56700 The variable is the round number - so `Round 1 of 12` where `1` is the variable

Comment: `str` doesn't have a `contains` method.  There is `str.__contains__` but it isn't called directly, the syntax `'something' in my_string` is used.

Answer (score 1):

For searching the string for a pattern like : "This is (\d\d) round of 12"
You can use regular expression for this :

```py
import re 
pattern = r'This is (\d\d) round of 12'
search_re = re.compile(pattern)
string = "This is 00 round of 12"
result = search_re.search(string)
if result :
    print(result.groups())
    round = result.groups()[0]
    print("Round is ",round)
```

Most of the code is self explainatory. Note : this code can't work with input if you are using round 1 instead of round 01. So we can modify our code to match this pattern in string and return the code.

```py
import re 
def checkpattern(string):
    pattern1 = r'This is (\d) round of 12'
    pattern2 = r'This is (\d\d) round of 12'
    search_re1 = re.compile(pattern1)
    search_re2 = re.compile(pattern2)
    result1 = search_re1.search(string)
    if result1:
        print(result1.groups())
        round = result1.groups()[0]
        print("Round is ",round)
        return int(round)
    result2 = search_re2.search(string)
    if result2:
        print(result2.groups())
        round = result2.groups()[0]
        print("Round is ",round)
        return int(round)

def main():
    string = "Hello This is 0 round of 12"
    round = checkpattern(string)

    

main()
```

Comment: I've had a shot at implementing this and it appears to work, would you care to take a look and make sure I'm not missing anything? https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8tPUsz0

Comment: @ScarySpice It seems good for me. Just change line 26, You have edited "." instead of "_"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by 2 steps.

```
round_variable = ("Round " + variable + "of 12")
if line.contains(round_variable):
```

Also, if the variable is an integer, you may need to make it a string:

```
if line.contains("Round " + str(variable) + " of 12")
```

Comment: It's `line.__contains__()`.

Comment: How does this work? Is, in this case, `variable` a new object? If so, can I use it?

@user56700 What's the difference? Thus far I've had no issue with `line.contains()`

Comment: Weird, I just tried and got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'` whereas when i used `>>> string.__contains__("s")` it returned `True` - String was set to 'test'

Comment: Oh. Perhaps that was part of my issue. I thought I had something wrong with my shebang.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:
Line is just an example of the input.

```
>>> line = "Round 10 of 12"
>>> if re.search(r"Round\s(\d)+\sof\s12", line):
...     print("Validation successful")
...
Validation successful

>>> line = "Round 4 of 12"
>>> if re.search(r"Round\s(\d)+\sof\s12", line):
...     print("Validation successful")
...
Validation successful
```

As per your code:

```
def roundfetch(roundline):
    if re.search(r"Round\s(\d)+\sof\s12", roundline):
        return(int(re.search(r"Round\s(\d)+\sof\s12", roundline).group(1)))
```

Comment: This only works if the string matches `Round 1 of 12`, though. `1` is entirely variable and can be any number up to 12

Comment: Variable is set to 1, if you change it, then the string changes too. Are you talking about the line variable?

Comment: I don't have the ability to change it, I need to *fetch* it once I've tested for this specific line. I don't actually know what the variable is going to be until the line is tested. This si why the `__contains__()` test needs to catch any iteration of round x.

Comment: @ScarySpice So you have the input "Round x of 12" and want to check if x is a number?

Comment: I know it's a number, I just don't know *what* number. I also need to identify that line in the first place, which is what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: I should also note that it isn't a number until I perform a conversion on it - `line` is always a string

Comment: @ScarySpice i'm very confused. What are the contents of line in regards to your question? Please give an example of line.

Comment: `line` could be "Round 1 of 12". It could be "Round 2 of 12". It could be "Round 10 of 12". If could be any number from 1-12, depending on what round is being played. `line` could also be "Round_commencing", or "TEAM_PLAYER_ADDED", or "NUM_HUMANS" or any other content related to the console output. 

I need to test if `line` matches the **format** "Round x of 12", and if so, get the value of x. I can do the latter easily, the former is where I'm having problems.

Comment: @ScarySpice check answer now, it's validating if the line has the structure you say and evaluates to True if it does.

Comment: Gotcha. I just tested Amit's implementation below, using the same `re` package and it appears to work. Yours is more compact, which I'll test out too